# No puedo crear un nuevo usuario quando en el json no conste con este

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, discord.js

Estoy intentando en node.js, coger una cantidad de dinero random la cual la genera "moneye" y se la quiero sumar(el dinero de moneye + el dinero que ya tenía en la base de datos) al usuario cuyo haya realizado la acción. El problema lo tengo en que no sé cómo hacer que si el usuario no existe crear uno nuevo con su id y con el valor de money = 0, y sumarle la cantidad que haya generado.

**Codigo JS**

```
            var moneywin = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
            console.log(interaction.user.id)//Me dice el usuario que ha echo la interaccón
            console.log(moneywin)//El número random generado
            var moneya = []
            var a = file_users
            const usuari = interaction.user.id
            Object.keys(file_users.users).forEach(user => {
                // console.log(file_users.users[user].ID)
                if (file_users.users[user].ID === 509000419935125570) /*aqui va interaction.users.id*/ {

                    moneya.push(file_users.users[user].Money)
                    var moneye = file_users.users[user].Money
                    var moneytotal = parseInt(moneye) + parseInt(moneywin)
                    if (isNaN(moneye)) { //Aqui e porvado de decir que si Money no es un numerp que lo genere, però no funciona
                        var newuser = {
                            ID: interaction.user.id,
                            Money: 0
                        }
                        console.log("let's go")
                            // file_users.push(newuser)
                    } else {
                        function UpdateMoneyById(id, newMoney) {
                            file_users.users.find(x => x.ID == id).Money = newMoney;
                        }

                        UpdateMoneyById(usuari, moneytotal);
                    }

                    //user.interaction.id
                    fs.writeFile('C:/Users/aleix/OneDrive/Escritorio/Terranoids/functions/prova1.json', JSON.stringify(file_users, null, 4), (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
```

**Archivo JSON**

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "ID": 509000419935125570,
            "Money": 5279
        },
        {
            "ID": 935554038815137900,
            "Money": 5726
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: en qué línea o parte del código que muestras te da el error que mencionas? porque veo que recorres un array de usuarios, así que entiendo que todos esos usuarios ya existen

Comment: Que dice tu titulo?? -Cuando-??

Comment: En la linea n13 Intento ver si el usuario que ha echo la inteeraccion(interaction.user.id) sale en el JSON, si no sale creo el newuser, si sale edito el valor money. El problema esta en la comparacion del if i en el push de crear un nuevo usuario.